# After Upgrade from Magento 2.1.6 to Magneto 2.3.2 i get below error

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

After upgade Magento 2.1.6 to 2.3.2 i am try to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade it's give below error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`latest`.`catalog_product_entity_datetime`, CONSTRAINT
>   `CAT_PRD_ENTT_DTIME_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON
>   DELETE C), query was: INSERT INTO
>               catalog_product_entity_datetime(attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, `value`)
>               VALUES
>               (:attribute_id0,:store_id0,:entity_id0,:value0),(:attribute_id1,:store_id1,:entity_id1,:value1),(:attribute_id2,:store_id2,:entity_id2,:value2)
>               ON duplicate KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`)

Please assist me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It means that the value of column **entity_id** in `catalog_product_entity_datetime` table does not exist in `catalog_product_entity` table. Bear in mind that the **entity_id** in `catalog_product_entity_*` tables must reflect an existing product in `catalog_product_entity` table.